# Forwarding calls from Apache server to cpp server both running on Raspberry

Tags: c++, apache, nginx, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry Pi B+ and i have installed both Apache server and my own cpp server, running on different ports. The cpp server is based on the 'GNU Libmicrohttpd' library and I can choose a specific port for it. The Apache server is running on port 80. I would like to put the Apache server in front and forward calls to my cpp server. I read that load balancing is supported by Raspberry; I have to install a lightweight proxy server like NGINX or Varnish in order to do this. 
My question is: Is there anyone who tried this? Does it actually work on the Raspberry? Other suggestions ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say cpp server?

Comment: I mean a server written in c++